# How to manually handle when Path Param is not present on the request url in NestJs?

Tags: typescript, validation, nestjs

I am new to Nest, and doing a project as I am learning. But today I got stuck doing the following thing:

```ts
@Delete('remove/:id')
removePartner(@Param() param: ParamDto) {
  return this.service.delete(param.id);
}
```

Where the `ParamDto` is like this:

```ts
export class ParamDto {
  @IsMongoId()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  id: string;
}
```

Now, I want to validate and throw error if the `id` is empty, but as soon as I just send a `DELETE` request to `/remove`, Nest returns the following error:

```json
{
    "message": "Cannot DELETE /remove/",
    "error": "Not Found",
    "statusCode": 404
}
```

I don't want the error to be thrown like that. What can I do?

I have tried having another route of just `/remove` like

```ts
@Delete('/remove')
@Delete('/remove/:id')
// ... rest of the code
```

But while it does throw the error from my validation, the `/remove/:id` route does not work anymore.

I also searched google and asked ChatGPT, but I don't think I am able to communicate my problem correctly, so I am getting result for validation the `@Param` which I am already doing, but not the issue I am facing.

Comment: I could do that. But is there any way I can do this using `Param`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `404` error means that Nest isn't able to find the route that you're trying to reach. The route `/remove/:id` isn't same as `/remove/`. When you do a `DELETE /remove/` it's considered as `DELETE /remove` and not `DELETE /remove/<missing-id>`.

You cannot use multiple route decorators on a controller function, if you do that, the last evaluated decorator (which would be the one that appears first on the list) will be considered, so for the code snippet -

```
@Delete('/remove')
@Delete('/remove/:id')
// ... rest of the code
```

The route will be mapped for `DELETE /remove` and not `DELETE /remove/:id`. You can verify that by looking at the logs from the Nest application, you'll see something along the lines of -

```
LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/remove, DELETE} route +0ms
```

If you want a controller function to be used for multiple routes with single http verb, you'll have to provide the paths in an array, something like this in your case -

```
@Delete(['/remove/:id', '/remove'])
removePartner(@Param() param: ParamDto) {
  return this.service.delete(param.id);
}
```

with that, if you try to `DELETE /remove` you'll get the error you're expecting. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work just as I expected! The only issue right now is that `@nestjs/swagger` is creating 2 different routes for the swagger file, but I will look into what I can do on that.